# Make optional argument required depending on inferred Type

Tags: typescript

I have an object that stores keys and callbacks. These callbacks can have either 1 argument or none (undefined).

Minimal example:

```
const foo = {
  a: (arg: string) => null,
  b: () => null,
}

type keys = keyof typeof foo
type FirstArgument<Key extends keys> = Parameters<(typeof foo)[Key]>[0]

function testing<T extends keys>(key: T, arg?: FirstArgument<T>) {
  foo[key](arg)
}

testing('a', 'bar') // No error => correct
testing('a', 5) // Error => correct
testing('b') // No error > correct
testing('b', 'baz') // Error => correct, 'baz' is not assignable to type undefined

testing('a') // No error, even though FirstArgument<T> is string
```

I understand that the `| undefined` part of an optional argument makes this a completely expected outcome. But is there any way to achieve what I'm looking for? I've tried overloading the function and spreading arguments but both didn't change the behavior.

Comment: Does something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgDZ4N) meet your needs? If so, I can write it as an answer. If not, what did I miss?

Comment: That's pretty much it. Please go ahead and solutify :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [rest parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#rest-parameters) with a [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#handbook-content) [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) type to create the desired function signature:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeAoGMCGAuGAChwCcBzA6EgSzDIEoUA+GMAVwBsOAaLGAIwKFGyFuy68AvgG4MGKAE8ADgFMYAMUQoYi1SDjxEs3WvXUS0AAqkcAWwA8AaRgqAHlBVgAJhBgBrFQV9DUQWVGsSOxUPC3tNEABtRwBdJgSABmTZDDg2MGAoanAdFWhaMicXd08ff0Dg+KZCPgCFAkdebAA6HtIyCAIzCygIuycWNw9vXzyvFThaFS8YAH4YBOSYAgS+wfMrGwdHJmSMegIANxBqZcxsBETW5OJyCAzkgEJ6WUk5DzK6IQAEQ4IHcGBA-ikIHfGAAejhMBAfnkpUKgMhMOk8MRyL+aPKwNBsLhACoYABREgkEAkIhuVQFJb0PjYNkwAB+XIwFNcjI8ywATLhyGxbJ4oBBwfw2LAyCBYABGLqEQUAVjVABZGKS4fiAWQiWCYGqSeSqTS6YQGSomV4WezHeyORgAIKi8VgWDBEwwADk7Fs-BUJD9MGovjACtwEAg1DIYBw-A4aigSCUh2iIaRBl9fqo5T9KsFAGZNaaYLr9ejDZjwZCcAAvLHw83U2n0vm2gUOp1OrkDnldu0wRUishiiVSgSymDy2CC4sa7WVvVAA)

```ts
const foo = {
  a: (arg: string) => null,
  b: () => null,
};

type Foo = typeof foo;
type FirstParam<K extends keyof Foo> = Parameters<Foo[K]>[0];

function testing<K extends keyof Foo>(
  key: K,
  ...args: FirstParam<K> extends undefined ? [] : [arg: FirstParam<K>]
): void {
  foo[key](args[0]!);
}

testing("a", "bar"); // ok
testing("b"); // ok

testing("a"); /* Error (expected)
        ~~~
Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.(2554) */

testing("a", 5); /* Error (expected)
             ~
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.(2345) */

testing("b", "baz"); /* Error (expected)
             ~~~~~
Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.(2554) */
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried rest arguments but have not coupled them with narrowing down to a tuple like you did. This is a neat solution and perfectly does the job for what I need. However, you are passing 'undefined' rather than nothing to the callback. Need to be mindful about that even though in most cases there's nothing wrong with that. Edit: with my example code, undefined would have been passed as well, so I shouldn't complain :D also, this could easily be avoided with a runtime check.
Cheers!